# Product collection based on "Set Product as New from Date"

Tags: product, product-collection, date

I want product collection based on "Set Product as New from Date".I have specify date for filter this.
Below is code :

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);
$storeId    = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_collection')
        ->addAttributeToSelect(Mage::getSingleton('catalog/config')->getProductAttributes())
        ->addMinimalPrice()
        ->addUrlRewrite()
        ->addTaxPercents()
        ->addStoreFilter()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date'=>true, 'to'=> $todayDate))
        ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute'=>'news_to_date', 'date'=>true, 'from'=>$todayDate), array('attribute'=>'news_to_date', 'is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null'))),'','left')
        ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date','desc');      
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_status')->addVisibleFilterToCollection($products);
    Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($products);

    $products->setPageSize($this->getConfig('qty'))->setCurPage(1);
    $this->setProductCollection($products);
```

Now issue : query is filtering a table "catalog_product_flat_2" but date (Set Product as New from Date) I set for product is saved in "catalog_product_entity_datetime" hence I am not gettnig proper
data.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$products= Mage::getModel('catalog/product_collection')
           ->clear()
           ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC');
```

Answer (score 0):

Please disable flat catalog for products from configuration and try again. You can do the same from  **System > Configuration** then under **Catalog**, click **Catalog**. You can find **Frontend** section on right.

From **Yes**, set to **No** for products.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `flat tables` in that case you need to enable **Used in Product Listing** to **Yes** from product attributes `frontend properties`. After that only it will appear in flat table.